# Python: make class method global

Tags: python, class, module, arguments, python-import

There are two modules: `main` and `my_module`. And there is a function `my_func` imported from `my_module` and used all over the main module like

```
#main.py
from my_module import my_func

def main_func1():
    #do smth
    my_func()
    #do smth

def main_func2():
    #do smth
    my_func()
    #do smth

def main():
    #do smth
    main_func1()
    my_func()
    main_func2()
    #do smth
```

The problem started when I have overriten the code in `my_module` so that now `my_func` is a method of a class.

If `my_func` was only in `main()` it would be preety easy to change main module

```
from my_module import myClass

def main():
    c = myClass(init_parameters)
    #do smth
    main_func1()
    c.my_func()
    main_func2()
    #do smth
```

But what about `main_func1` and `main_func2`? How could I make instance and it's method been used as in example before? Is there any other solution except passing it as argument or creating another one in every function?

Comment: Is that a **class** method or an **instance** method? Because you seem to be calling it on instance.

Comment: Instance method. Sorry, i'm not good at terminology and OOP at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have said, if you're expecting `my_func` to behave like a global function but as a method in a class, it should be a static method or class method. Here is an example - this is the contents of `foo.py`:

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def say_hello():
        print("hello")
```

Now in `main.py` you could do:

```
from foo import Foo

say_hello = Foo.say_hello

def func1():
    say_hello()

def main():
    say_hello()
    func1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This successfully outputs

```
hello
hello
```

The way I've made `say_hello` look like a global function in `main.py` is simply by assigning `Foo.say_hello` to `say_hello` in the global scope. This is entirely possible due functions being first class objects in Python.
from foo import Foo

Accounting for it having to be an instance method:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

    def say(self):
        print(self.msg)
```

The foo mockup has had to change a bit. Remember that it should only be an instance method if you expect it to behave differently on which instance it is called on, so in this case, `say` must be an instance method as it relies on the `msg` value of its instance.

```
from foo import Foo

def func1():
    say()

def main():
    global say
    f = Foo("hello")
    say = f.say
    say()
    func1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This still works, although to be honest it's getting to sloppy coding style now. If your functions need to access a method of a specific instance, you should probably pass the instance to them. Using the `global` keyword is already often slightly foggy territory, and I'd say that's doubly true when you're using it for an instance method.

```
from foo import Foo

def func1(f):
    f.say()

def main():
    f = Foo("hello")
    f.say()
    func1(f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also works fine. You seemed a bit apprehensive about having to change your code to work with your new model for `my_func`, but to be honest I'd say it's not too much of a big deal to do a bit of refactoring.

Comment: I've just seen that it should be an instance method.. I'll try and update